# How to plot multichannel power spectrum in python

Tags: python, plot, signal-processing, fft, spectrum

how to plot multi channel spectrum plot? each channel is a abs(fft(timeseries))**2[image]

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/

Comment: The image at https://gist.github.com/fasiha/957035272009eb1c9eb370936a6af2eb#results-on-8192-sample-chunks-of-full-data is made using the code at https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fasiha/957035272009eb1c9eb370936a6af2eb/raw/8663ef33d53c0b752b71468a7b552e03a4721292/code.py (see `plt.imshow(db20(hpsArr) ...`)

Comment: uhm, but it's only onechanel, in this image there's more than 16 channels
each column is a frequency, each line a channel, and each color a magnetude value